# How to do a bidirectional SSH connection on localhost?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I need to use a bidirectional SSH connection on localhost. I have a user called **barman** and other called **postgres**. As **barman** user, I created a RSA key, and copied its public key to the file var/lib/postgres/.ssh/authorized_keys. Then, as **postgres** user, I created another RSA key and copied its public key to the file var/lib/barman/.ssh/authorized_keys.

But now, as **barman** user, for example, when I do `ssh postgres@localhost` I get the error message:

`Permission denied (publickey).`

And same result from **postgres** user. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I had to press the Enter key after the SSH key in each authorized_keys file. Now it can read both keys in both way.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check why you want to do ssh to the `postgres` account. That
   account probably isn't intended to be used in that way.
2. Check that `/var/lib/postgres` is `postgres`'s home directory.
3. Check that the `.ssh` directory and the `authorized_keys` are not group- or world-readable.

Comment: 1. I was told to do it in that way,
2. Yes, it is,
3. Why that? authorized_keys is not group-world readable, but .ssh is.

Comment: [Have your tried disabling group read access?](http://superuser.com/questions/633889/ssh-public-key-stopped-to-be-accepted-after-changes-to-group-permisssions?rq=1) Does `~postgres/.ssh` have any configuration files? Do `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` or `/ect/ssh/sshd_config` contain anything special? It is possible to disable or limit access there.